# C# WPF Setting file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, settings

I need your help.
I created a file "flick.settings" and a bool variable in it called "prop".
When a user checks one of the checkboxes and hits the button, the code should "remember" that prop's value is true and on the next launch it should appear as checked. So, the value must remain even when I replace .exe file with another copy.
Here's a part of my code:

```
private void remember_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.oneone.IsChecked == true)
        {
            flick.Default.prop = true;
            flick.Default.Save();
        }
        else if (this.oneone.IsChecked == false)
        {
            flick.Default.prop = false;
            flick.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

And to access the variable:

```
private void show_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flick.Default.prop == true)
        {
            this.oneone.IsChecked = true;
        }
        else if (flick.Default.prop == false)
        {
            this.oneone.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
```

But when I change the value in flick.settings and save it, my so called program appears to "remember" that bool value inside of it, not in the flick.settings. So, my question is how can I do it right? Help me, please!

Comment: the whole code your write above can be replaced by just this `flick.Default.prop = oneone.IsChecked; flick.Default.Save();` This is just the code used to save the value. You need the code to load it.

Comment: Any ideas how to load it?

Comment: just access it normally (as a property): `flick.Default.prop`

Comment: the accessing code is also simpler like this `oneone.IsChecked = flick.Default.prop;` (no need that long if-else statements)